Why would I need `DangerousAddRef`/`DangerousRelease` around `DangerousGetHandle`?
I've been looking into the Microsoft.Windows.CsWin32 NuGet package and comparing the P/Invoke code it generates to what I would write by hand. In some cases it uses SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef/SafeHandle.DangerousRelease when I wouldn't have. I'm trying to understand why, and haven't come up with anything.
Here's an example for the Win32 SetInformationJobObject function:
[DllImport("KERNEL32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
[DefaultDllImportSearchPaths(DllImportSearchPath.System32)]
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows5.1.2600")]
internal static extern unsafe winmdroot.Foundation.BOOL SetInformationJobObject(winmdroot.Foundation.HANDLE hJob, winmdroot.System.JobObjects.JOBOBJECTINFOCLASS JobObjectInformationClass, void* lpJobObjectInformation, uint cbJobObjectInformationLength);

/// <inheritdoc cref="AssignProcessToJobObject(winmdroot.Foundation.HANDLE, winmdroot.Foundation.HANDLE)"/>
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows5.1.2600")]
internal static unsafe winmdroot.Foundation.BOOL AssignProcessToJobObject(SafeHandle hJob, SafeHandle hProcess)
{
    bool hJobAddRef = false;
    bool hProcessAddRef = false;
    try
    {
        winmdroot.Foundation.HANDLE hJobLocal;
        if (hJob is object)
        {
            hJob.DangerousAddRef(ref hJobAddRef);
            hJobLocal = (winmdroot.Foundation.HANDLE)hJob.DangerousGetHandle();  // <-- THIS
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hJob));
        winmdroot.Foundation.HANDLE hProcessLocal;
        if (hProcess is object)
        {
            hProcess.DangerousAddRef(ref hProcessAddRef);
            hProcessLocal = (winmdroot.Foundation.HANDLE)hProcess.DangerousGetHandle();
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hProcess));
        winmdroot.Foundation.BOOL __result = PInvoke.AssignProcessToJobObject(hJobLocal, hProcessLocal); // calls the `extern` overload
        return __result;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (hJobAddRef)
            hJob.DangerousRelease();
        if (hProcessAddRef)
            hProcess.DangerousRelease();
    }
}

I expected the second function to something like:
[DllImport("KERNEL32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows5.1.2600")]
internal static unsafe winmdroot.Foundation.BOOL AssignProcessToJobObject(SafeHandle hJob, SafeHandle hProcess)
{
    var localJob = (winmdroot.Foundation.HANDLE)hJob.DangerousGetHandle();
    var localProcess = (winmdroot.Foundation.HANDLE)hProcess.DangerousGetHandle();
    return (winmdroot.Foundation.BOOL)PInvoke.AssignProcessToJobObject(localJob, localProcess);
}

It seems to be making a defensive copy of the handle, but I don't see how that would help anything. Even if the handle held by the SafeHandle changes—which AFAIK it shouldn't—we'd still be passing some handle into the extern overload.
I tried checking out the source generator's code for hints, and found the commit that added the calls, but that doesn't tell me. I'm assuming that it was based on what the marshaler would have done with a SafeHandle.
Any ideas on why we need to increase the reference count here?

No, SafeHandle isn't there to prevent changes, it stops accidental closing of a handle.  A concrete problem with classes that deal with handles, they always have a finalizer and the GC can't see that a handle is being used by a winapi function.  This isn't pretty code btw.

Surrounding the usage of a COM object with extra AddRef and Release ensures your code won't fail/crash if some other portion of code (like in multithreading scenarios) calls the last needed Release on it and so releases the object from memory it while you're using it. Usually it's not needed since when you got a COM reference you already had an implicit AddRef done by called code, but generators are dumb and have not details of the conditions that led here.

Yeah, I definitely agree for the COM case--the mere fact that we have a SafeHandle means that we're holding a COM reference to the object, so we don't need to increment/decrement the counter for that purpose.
I'm more wondering about the non-COM situation. In this example, it's a win32 function.

I think why I'm confused is that I don't understand the intended sharing model of SafeHandle. Since it's IDisposable, I assumed that it has a clear owner, and that the owner is responsible for not disposing it until it's no longer in use. But the DangerousAddRef/DangerousRelease imply some sort of sharing without coordination.

From the official docs:
SafeHandle.DangerousGetHandle

Using the DangerousGetHandle method can pose security risks because,
if the handle has been marked as invalid with SetHandleAsInvalid,
DangerousGetHandle still returns the original, potentially stale
handle value. The returned handle can also be recycled at any point.
At best, this means the handle might suddenly stop working. At worst,
if the handle or the resource that the handle represents is exposed to
untrusted code, this can lead to a recycling security attack on the
reused or returned handle. For example, an untrusted caller can query
data on the handle just returned and receive information for an
entirely unrelated resource.
[emphasis mine:] See the DangerousAddRef and the
DangerousRelease methods for more information about using the
DangerousGetHandle method safely.

SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef

The DangerousAddRef method prevents the common language runtime from
reclaiming memory used by a handle (which occurs when the runtime
calls the ReleaseHandle method). You can use this method to manually
increment the reference count on a SafeHandle instance. [...].

So this seems to be to make sure that the handle doesn't get invalidated while you use it.
